# how to make a cursor follower same position/size of another div while hovering this element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a cursor element that follows the mouse X and Y position. But once it hovers a text element of the menu, I want this cursor follower to change in size and position.

Size = to the offset width and height of the text being hovered
position = to remain at offset Y and X of that text being hovered and only while being hovered.

So far I have this but I believe is not working. Any suggestions on how should I continue? thanks for your kind words!

```js
let cursor = document.querySelector('.cursorFollower');

let button = document.querySelector('.superText');
let buttonWidth = button.offsetWidth;
let buttonHeight = button.offsetHeight;
let buttonX = button.offsetLeft;
let buttonY = button.offsetTop;

document.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>{
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX - 10 + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY - 10 + 'px';   
});

button.onmouseover = function(){
  button.setAttribute("style", "color: #84C4B5;");
  cursor.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
  cursor.style.width = buttonWidth + 'px';
  cursor.style.height = buttonHeight + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = buttonY + 'px';
};

button.onmouseout = function(){
  button.setAttribute("style", "color: white;");
  cursor.style.transform = 'rotate(45deg)';
  cursor.style.width = '20px';
  cursor.style.height = '20px';
};
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0A193E;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.superText {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.cursorFollower {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="superText">Hello World!</p>
</div>

<div class="cursorFollower"></div>
```

Comment: Well it’s for sure not gonna work if you arbitrarily switch from the correct spelling of the method name, `setAttribute`, to the non-existing `SetAttribute`.

Comment: good point @CBroe but I've updated that on my codepen and still not work. I might be doing another thing wrong?

Comment: Should this be `cursor.setAttribute("left",buttonX);` to `cursor.setAttribute("style", "left: " + buttonX);` ?

Comment: thanks @Shuvo, no luck though

Comment: I've edited the snippet @MrOutadi but cannot make work the positioning of the cursorFollower (I want it to retain the same X and Y of the text while hovering on top of the text. that way is static while hovering on top of that text/button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your first problem was that you used `SetAttribute` that is false and you should use `setAttribute`. (just attend to camelcase!)
2. And the second thing you didn't notice is that `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` aren't element attributes. they are for the `style` attribute!

so please use this code:

```js
button.onmouseover = function (e) {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", `left: ${buttonX}, top: ${buttonY}, width: ${buttonWidth}, height: ${buttonHeight}`);
};
```

Comment: thanks @MrOutadi but for some reason, after updating that line it still doesn't work

Comment: Hello @MrOutadi! finally made it work (partially) I finally made the div same size as the button, but I cannot make to keep same position (x and y) as the button while hovering on top of the button. like to become the border of the button while hovering on top of it. and only once the cursor is away from the button to retain it's actual x and y?

Comment: @Eugenio, wait, I just fixed the hover bug, I read this comment now so I'm going to fix click :)

Comment: thanks @MrOutadi :)! I've updated the snippet a bit. I know the issue has to do with the positioning of the cursor based on the client X and Y so 'I'm trying to implement an if statement checking the offset Y and X compared to the button X and Y to allow this movement to happen or to place it on top of the button x and y in case is touching the button. A bit complex, not an expert on this haha

Comment: @Eugenio would you please take a look at this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/onmouseover-or-onmouseenter-n4neo

Comment: @Eugenio, please change the myWay variable to see my another way.
here I have 3 way for getting button click:
1. get cursor click (you don't even need to make it out of comment.
2. get button position and match that with clicked event position.
3. is that never try to set cursor top of your div cause you can't access your element under the cursor

Comment: Wowwww this was beautifully solved @MrOutadi !!! a lot of things happened there, I need to read carefully your code to understand what's going on but love it! that's exactly what I was trying to do :D!

Comment: hello @MrOutadi :)! one quick question, what if I have several texts with same class name? I can target only the hovered one?

Comment: @Eugenio Yesss
I have a way for that but text me to talk about that instead of telling you directly ;)
text me with my id on telegram or Twitter to talk more about that and I'll help you